# Isabelle Type Error

Tags: types, isabelle

I am new to Isabelle and doing an Exercise for University. I need to proof a reverse function in Isabelle.

In Haskell the function would look like this:

```
rev [] = []
rev (x:xs) = rev xs ++ [x]
```

I now tryed to define this function "rev" in Isabelle. The type list and the function "app" (append)

[image: function app and rev in Isabelle]

The Error Isabelle gives me is:

```
Type unification failed: Clash of types "_
          ⇒ _" and "_ Exercise5.list"

Type error in application: incompatible operand type

Operator:  app (rev xs) ::
  'a Exercise5.list ⇒ 'a Exercise5.list
Operand:   Exercise5.list.Cons ::
  ??'a ⇒ ??'a Exercise5.list ⇒ ??'a Exercise5.list
```

Where is the Problem? As far as I understand it Isabelle is telling me "Hey buddy app needs 2 arguments of type **a' list** but this is not the case here"

but why? **xs** is clearly of type **a' list** and with my Cons operator i do make x also a list?

Thanks for the Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about where the parenthesis should be put in `app rev xs Cons x Nil`: Currently you seem to apply the function `x` on its argument `Nil`.

Comment: Thank you! Cons(x Nil) should be **(Cons x Nil)** That solved my little Issue. Thanks :)